# why is this warning ( no return , in function returning non-void)?

Tags: c, linux, timer, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

```
void *rastertask()
{
    struct sched_param sparm;
    memset(&sparm, 0, sizeof(sparm));
    sparm.sched_priority = 10; /* 0 = lowest, 99 = highest */

    sched_setscheduler(
            0 /* pid, 0 ==> this process */,
            SCHED_RR /* policy */,
            &sparm);

    unsigned int n_loop;
    for(n_loop=0;;n_loop++) {
        struct timespec ts_start, ts_end;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts_start);

        TASK1(Task2ms_Raster); /* gets called every 2ms */
        if( (n_loop % 5) == 0) {
            TASK2(Task10ms_Raster); /* get called every 5 * 2ms = 10ms */
        }
        if( (n_loop % 50) == 0) {
            TASK3(Task100ms_Raster); /* get called every 50 * 2ms = 100ms */
        }

        if( (n_loop % 250) == 0 ) {
            /* reset loop counter when smallest common
             * multiple of timing grid has been reached */
            n_loop = 0;
        }

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts_end);
        useconds_t const tasks_execution_time = delta_t_us(&ts_start, &ts_end);

        if( tasks_execution_time >= MS_to_US(2) ) {
            /* report an error that tasks took longer than 2ms to execute */
        }

        /* wait for 2ms - task_execution_time so that tasks get called in
         * a close 2ms timing grid */

        else
            usleep( MS_to_US(2) - tasks_execution_time );
    }

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

               pthread_t thread_id

                if (pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &rastertask, NULL)) {
                               perror ("pthread_create");
                               exit (1);
                }

return 0;
}
```

I am creating a thread in the main function. Created a scheduler in the function for calling the tasks for every 2milli seconds, 10 milli seconds and 100 milliseconds. 
I am getting a warning in the void *rastertask() as NO return, in function returning non-void.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you promise to return a void pointer but you don't. hence the warning.

`void*` is not the same as `void` as a return type.

<s>you probably wanted to define the function as</s>

```
void rastertask()
```

**edit:**

ok so you need the function to be defined as `void *` in order to be used with `pthread_create()`. in that case, you need to add a return statement even if it will return the null pointer.

Comment: I changed itto void rastertask ?? but again warning: passing argument 3 of pthread_create from incompatible pointer type.

Comment: If I add return 0 then there is no warning!! is that the right way to add return 0 for the void function??

Comment: as long as you are sure that nobody will ever try to dereference the returned value - yes, it is fine.

Comment: I am just calling the task in that function for every 2ms, 10ms and 100ms!! so I think, it wont be a problem.